# Retrieve image from SQL Server using ASP.NET web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a SQL Server (2008 R2) with an Image table, the table has a column with type image. I insert my Image into this column using

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

//insert the file into database
string strQuery = "insert into pm005.images(imageName, type, alt, img)" + " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Alt, @Data)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Alt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
InsertUpdateData(cmd);
lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";

private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    // Open a connection the the SQL Server
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=sql-server;integrated security=SSPI;database=pm005";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This i believe works fine, because the insert returns true, and i can see the data in the database.

However i cant for the life of me see how i'm supposed to get this image back out. Specifically what i want is to be able to call my web service, pass it the imageID and have the image (and only the image) returned to me. Much like its done with PHP. THis is the code im using now.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public System.Drawing.Image  getImage(int imageID, string uName, string pword)
{
    string str="";
 try
 {
     SqlCommand cmd = getSQLCommand("SELECT img FROM pm005.images WHERE id="+imageID);

 byte[] Img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

  // Convert the image record to file stream and display it to picture control
  str = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(str, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
  fs.Write(Img, 0, Img.Length);
  fs.Flush();
  fs.Close();

 }
 catch
 {

 }
 finally
 {

 }

 System.Drawing.Image theImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(str);
 return theImage;

}
```

Which gives the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.Drawing.IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(String fileName)
   at System.Drawing.IntSecurity.DemandReadFileIO(String fileName)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at WebService2.Service1.getImage(Int32 imageID, String uName, String pword)
```

I've looked at so many tutorials, and not find any solid answer except "use PHP". If i have to i will, but surely there must be a way to do it in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the Full FilePath:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\YourFile.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
```

**Edit:**

Rather than using the File System it sounds like you want to do it in memory:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

...

```
 System.Drawing.Image theImage = null;
 try
 {
     SqlCommand cmd = getSQLCommand("SELECT img FROM pm005.images WHERE id="+imageID);
     byte[] Img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     theImage = byteArrayToImage(Img);
 }
 catch
 {

 }
 finally
 {

 }    
 return theImage;    
}
```

Comment: There is no full path, the image is stored in the DB

Comment: When you retrieve the image from the DB you are trying to write it to disk. I can see in the call stack it fails here: `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`. Can you double check you are using the 6th overload of the `FileStream` method which requires a filePath for the 1st argument in the parameter?

Comment: Yes I am, but that's just because the tutorial told me to. I don't know why i'm passing it a path that i just the time.

Comment: Your edit, is a great first step thank you, i get a result, just not an image.



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Image xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />



I'm not using your imageToByteArray to place the image into the DB, would that be why? I'm trying to change it now to work with the FileUpload control that i use to select the image.

Comment: If you continue to have problems simply follow this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database